# Why Pressable component's ripple effect only trigger on long press

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-component

I'm using new pressable component of react native thinking that it's easy to add ripple effect to it.
But, I found that the ripple effect is being triggered only on long press.

i.e To see the ripple, I need to touch the button for atleast 120ms to 150ms. a rough guess.

I tried to recreate the issue on `snack.expo.io` but i'm getting `Minified React error #130;` I think snack won't support pressable.

I didn't found answer anywhere. And there is a active issue on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29488) about this. But no where I found any workaround for this issue.

So, If anyone has a workaround for this kindly share here as it will help so many like me.

This is the code to add pressable with ripple effect

```
      <Pressable
        style={styles.buttonStyle}
        android_ripple={{color: 'black', borderless: true}}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </Pressable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just explored different links followed by the GitHub link you provided and finally found a [workaround](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29376#issuecomment-663110115).

Accordingly, you just have to add a prop `onPress={() => {}}` on your code even if you don't use it.

This will solve the ripple delay problem.

Comment: What If I already have an `onPress` on my `Pressable` ?